# Is it impossible to indicate the start of the input string using a multiline regex pattern in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

In JavaScript, the [multiline flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) changes the meaning of `^` and `$`:

> Treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working over multiple lines (i.e., match the beginning or end of each line (delimited by \n or \r), not only the very beginning or end of the whole input string)

Well, with those characters out of the picture, are there any *other* ways to mark the start of the input string? How can I indicate that I want my multiline pattern to *only* match at the start of the input string?

I know I can check the index of the match using the `index` property of the return value of `exec`, but is there a way to prevent the regex engine from searching the entire string in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JavaScript doesn't support the absolute anchors (`\A`, `\Z` and `\z`) like most other flavors do.  But are you sure you need them?  The beginning of the string is usually the only place where you **must** use an anchor.  Each subsequent line is automatically "anchored" by the newline preceding it.

I suggest you drop the multiline flag and make sure you explicitly consume all the newlines.  I know that's kinda vague; if you were to supply a code sample and/or tell us what problem you're trying to solve,  we might be able to do better.

Comment: I'm using my pattern to capture repeating lines, so I need to use line boundaries to account for when the repeating lines are against the "edges" of the input string (I can't simply make the line breaks optional, because they're only optional if against the edges). For my solution, I'm going to test the index of the match, as I mentioned in my question. I'm giving you `+1` because your suggestion might be useful to someone else.

Comment: Update: Actually, due to performance issues, I hacked up a solution that solves the issues I described above. I'll post a link to the code once I put it online. I s'pose you get the check!

Answer (score 2):

No, `^` is the only [built-in assertion](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.2.6) that tests for beginning-of-input and, as you said, its behavior is modified by the `multiline` flag.

You could put some unique string at the beginning of the string you're testing and also at the beginning of your regular expression, but that's a bit of a hack. In the normal case, as you said, you'd test the index of the returned match.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, with the growing adoption of the ECMAScript 2018+ standard that supports the lookbehind construct in a `RegExp`, you can now use an "absolute", unambiguous start of string position in the multiline mode regex if you use

```js
/^(?<![^])/gm
```

Although the `g` flag allows multiple matching and `m` allows `^` to match any line start position, the `^(?<![^])` pattern only matches

- `^` - start of a line that
- `(?<![^])` - has no char immediately to the left of it. `[^]` matches any char in an ECMAScript regex.

*Alternatives*:

```js
/^(?<![\w\W])/gm
/^(?<!.)/gsm
```

where `[\w\W]` matches any chars including line breaks (a synonymic contruct to `[\s\S]` and `[\d\D]`), and `/s` flag makes `.` line break aware.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const regex = /^(?<![^])/gm; // g - multiple matching enabled!
const text = 'Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3';
console.log(text.replace(regex, 'INSERTION...')); // Only the first line affected
// => INSERTION...Line 1
//    Line 2
//    Line 3
```